# WebClient "The message length limit was exceeded"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, webclient

I'm trying to download a little file (120kb) from my website using System.Net.WebClient object, but I get this error: "The message length limit was exceeded".

```
string url = "http://0.0.0.0/test.txt";
WebClient MyWebClient = new WebClient();
string download = MyWebClient.DownloadString(url);
```

I've already put `maxRequestLength` in my config file and set `FileSizeLimitInBytes` registry key, but with no results. Same problem in ansync download.
System: .NET 4.0, Windows XP.

thank you,
Riccardo

Comment: You might try setting `HttpWebRequest.MaximumResponseHeadersLength` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.maximumresponseheaderslength.aspx)

Comment: After setting MaximumResponseHeadersLength I get this error:
"The underlying connection was closed"

Comment: Set MaximumResponseHeadersLength to -1, it will be unlimited